# what " : " symbol meas in variable declaration?

Tags: c++

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // single parameter constructor, can be used as an implicit conversion
    Foo(int foo) : m_foo(foo)
    {
    }

    int GetFoo() { return m_foo; }
    unsigned int    mDoNotify : 1;
private:
    int m_foo;
};
```

can anyone pleas tell me what this line of code means -

```
unsigned int    mDoNotify : 1;
```

This is 1st time i encountered this kind of variable declaration.

TIA

Comment: @tadman - You've got the wrong `:`.    Look up bitfields.    https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: @Peter Thanks man. i did not know of bitfields till now. lot to learn :)